# ios UIDocumentMenuViewController not display files

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I want to import file from file list.I have used UIDocumentMenuViewController to display and select file. It shows blank screen when open iCloud.[image]

I have created UIDocumentMenuViewController which show all types of files.

```
UIDocumentMenuViewController *documentPickerMenu = [[UIDocumentMenuViewController alloc]
                                                    initWithDocumentTypes:@[@"public.item"]
                                                    inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
documentPickerMenu.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:documentPickerMenu animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I have implemented delegate methods.

```
- (void)documentMenu:(UIDocumentMenuViewController *)documentMenu didPickDocumentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)documentPicker{
documentPicker.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:documentPicker animated:YES completion:nil];  }

- (void)documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller didPickDocumentAtURL:(NSURL *)url {
if (controller.documentPickerMode == UIDocumentPickerModeImport)
{

    // Condition called when user download the file
    NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    // NSData of the content that was downloaded - Use this to upload on the server or save locally in directory


    //Showing alert for success
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        NSString *alertMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Successfully downloaded file %@", [url lastPathComponent]];
        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
                                              alertControllerWithTitle:@"UIDocumentView"
                                              message:alertMessage
                                              preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil]];
        [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

    });
} }
```

I have images on iCloud.I have tried same thing by creating UIDocumentPickerViewController instead of UIDocumentMenuViewController but same issu.I am not able to identify issue can anyone have any idea?

Comment: did you tried to logout and login from icloud account?

Comment: still same, not display any files.

Comment: try to delete and reinstall app

Comment: reinstallation not worked. it shows exact same page.

Comment: Some users/devs suggest rebooting the device a couple of times.

Comment: My guess is you did not put the appropriate key in Info.plist. These days you need permission from user to access anything on the iOS.